# OpenCV Spatial Matching (Beyond Bags of Featues, Lazebnik)

Tags: opencv

I am trying to create spatial representation of features. Basically, an image is subdivided into grids, e.g. 4 grids, and features are detected for each grid. Features are clustered into visual words. Histograms are created for each grid and then I can match the corresponding grids with histogram intersection. Here is the paper http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/cvpr06b_lana.pdf that I am working on it. First of all, how can I subdivide an image and detect features? I found out `GridAdaptedFeatureDetector` in Opencv but I do not know how to get features for particular grid. I can define a region of interest and detect features separately and add them into histogram but this sounds complicated and time wasting. Maybe there is an easy way to do. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997661/spatial-pyramid-matching-spm-for-sift-then-input-to-svm-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Your question is basically how one could implement her paper. The good news are that prof. Lazebnik has shared the source code or her Spatial Pyramid here:

http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~slazebni/research/SpatialPyramid.zip

Nevertheless, it is a matlab implementation that you would have to convert to OpenCV if you want.

You can also take a look at here [slides](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~slazebni/slides/ima_poster.pdf) and the dataset used is [here](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~slazebni/research/scene_categories.zip).